# How to minimize the time it takes to iterate through all possible combinations of a 4-digit PIN, if any of the digits are already known?

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, combinations, brute-force

If I were to brute-force a PIN, I could iterate through all the possible PINs with this code:

```js
for (PIN = 0000; PIN <= 9999; PIN++) {
  console.log(String(PIN).padStart(4, '0'));
}
```

But if I know that the second digit is `3` and the last digit is `7`, I'm wasting time iterating over impossible combinations.

I could check for the validity of a combination inside the loop, like this:

```js
for (PIN = 0000; PIN <= 9999; PIN++) {
  if (String(PIN)[1] != '3' || String(PIN)[3] != '7') {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(String(PIN).padStart(4, '0'));
}
```

But I want to avoid iterating over impossible combinations entirely.  How can I accomplish this?

---

I'm not actually brute-forcing a PIN.  I'm trying to brute-force the solution to a magic square for [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207331/complete-the-magic-square) competition.  But I presume more people are familiar with cracking passwords then solving magic squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the 2 unknown digits seperately.

```js
let timestamp = performance.now();

for(let digit1 = 0; digit1 < 10; digit1++) {
  for(let digit2 = 0; digit2 < 10; digit2++) {
    const digit = digit1 + "3" + digit2 + "7";
    
    //console.log(digit);
  }
}

console.log("first iteration took " + (performance.now() - timestamp) + "ms");

timestamp = performance.now();

for (PIN = 0000; PIN <= 9999; PIN++) {
  if (String(PIN)[1] != '3' || String(PIN)[3] != '7') {
    continue;
  }
  
  //console.log(String(PIN).padStart(4, '0'));
}

console.log("second iteration took " + (performance.now() - timestamp) + "ms");
```

Comment: I hope you realize that 0000 is the seen as 0, so your code `String(PIN)[1]` will most likely fail. I guess undefined in this case

Comment: OP used `padStart`

Comment: OP used `padStart` for the result, not the if statement. I simply copied his loop and added `performance.now()` to display the estimated timelapse. As for my iteration with logging `digit`, `digit` is a string and not an integer, if that's what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested loops for the digits you don't know, then combine them with the digits you know.

```
for (let first_digit = 0; first_digit <= 9000; first_digit += 1000) {
    for (let third_digit = 0; third_digit <= 90; third_digit += 10) {
        let PIN = first_digit + 300 + third_digit + 7;
        console.log(String(PIN).padStart(4, '0'));
    }
}
```